# Recording Elektron Analog Four in Ableton

Tags: synthesizer, ableton-live

I trying to record what I play in Elektron four in Ableton:

1.- Connecting the MIDI out of your Focusrite to the MIDI in on Elektron Analog Four

2.- Connecting the audio out of the hardware device to the input on your audio interface switched to Inst.

3.- Connecting the MIDI sync. out A of Elektron Analog Four to the MIDI in port on Focusrite Scarlett 2I4

I can hear the syhtn, control, play MIDI notes, I see on the external ins. plugin the green leds of the volume flashing, but not on the MIDI external ins. track…

[image]